# Examples of the large sieve inequality where a constant larger than 1 is needed

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sieve-theory

Let $S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n e^{2 \pi i n x}$ be a trigonometric polynomial of length $N$. The analytic/harmonic large sieve inequality in its sharpest form states that

$$ \sum_{r=1}^R |S(x_r)|^2  \leq (N + \delta^{-1}-1) \int_{0}^{1} |S(x)|^2 dx$$

where $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_R$ are $\delta$ separated points. This can be thought of as a discretization of Parseval's identity on the circle.

In many of the applications of this inequality to number theory one takes $\delta = 1/N$ in which case the right hand side of the inequality has a factor $2N$.

The factor of $2$ here leads to some very unfortunate inefficiencies in sieve theoretic applications, such as the $2$ in the Brun-Titchmarsh inequality. It seems that improving the factor of $2$ in these applications is related to both the parity problem in sieve theory and the Siegel zero problem. See, for instance, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.1777.pdf) of Maynard.

However it is easy to see in some cases, such as when $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_R$ are equally spaced (using Fourier analysis on the group of residues mod $N$), that the inequality indeed holds with a constant $1$ in place of the constant $2$.

> > Are there examples of trigonometric polynomials and $\delta = 1/N$ separated points known where the constant in the analytic large sieve inequality is required to be greater than $1$?

Comment: You want $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$ to be $\delta$-separated on the circle with $\delta=1/N$. This means that $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$ are *equally* spaced, so it seems that the sentence before your question answers the question.

Comment: I think you meant Parseval and not Parsavel. I don't have edit privileges so I won't change it but it might be useful to the interested reader.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: I fixed this, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @GH, the question should be posed with $m$ points which is permitted to be less than $N$ which eliminates the issue you identified. I have reworded the question. It seems Selberg's examples require $\delta^{-1} | N-1$ so one has no hope of getting a constant greater than $3/2$ from these. What's particularly interesting to me is that question of if the constant $2$ can be reduced is a purely analytic issue which, if true, would seems to have very deep arithmetic consequences.

Comment: @MarkLewko: I am still confused. Selberg gave an example with $R=N-1$ equidistant points (which are certainly $1/N$-separated) and $\sum_{r=1}^R |S(x_r)|^2  = (2N-2) \int_{0}^{1} |S(x)|^2 dx$. This means that you cannot reduce the constant $2$ for $\delta=1/N$. BTW I changed your $m$ to $R$ to harmonize with the notation of Montgomery and Tenenbaum (and also with the variable $r$).

Comment: @GH, I'm confused myself. Isn't Selberg's example a single exponential at frequency N-1 in this case, in which case the rhs of the expression on page 559 should be (N-1)|a|^2?

Comment: Here is Selberg's example in the relevant special case. Let $R=N-1$, and let $x_r:=r/(N-1)$. Let $a_1=a_N=1$, and let $a_n=0$ otherwise. Then $|S(x_r)|=2$ for each $r=1,\dots,R$, whence $\sum_{r=1}^R|S(x_r)|^2=4R=4N-4=(2N-2)\int_0^1|S(x)|^2dx$. So we have $1/N$ separated points (in fact $1/(N-1)$ equidistant points) with a constant $2N-2$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Ack. That's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments:

1) Montgomery's survey paper
https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183540922

page 559, Theorem 3 and equation (19). 
It essentially says that Selberg gave an example,
with the comment that this is the only situation where this is sharp.

See also page 563 for lower bounds on $\Delta$, and also upper bounds, when one is sieving modulo
some subset of the integers $q\leq Q$.

This paper gives links to the rich literature of that time.

2) Similarly, also some comments after Theorem 4.7 of
Tenenbaum's Introduction to analytic and probabilistic number theory, (3rd edition).

Two more recent items, maybe not so well known:

3)
Vandermonde Matrices with Nodes in the Unit Disk
and the Large Sieve,
C\'eline Aubel and Helmut Bölcskei
https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02538

4) Refinements of Selberg's sieve, 
Sara Elizabeth Blight, PhD Thesis, Rutgers, 2010.

Especially chapter 4
https://rucore.libraries.rutgers.edu/rutgers-lib/27420/

Comment: I don't think that Selberg's example answers the question. In Montgomery's notation, the example requires $R\mid N-1$ sample points, i.e. less than $N$ sample points. The OP wants $N$ sample points with $\delta=1/N$. So the OP's sample points are necessarily equidistributed at which point I am getting confused myself, so I will ask him in a remark. Note also that Montgomery has a typo: in the display below (19), $\frac{N-1}{R}R+1$ should be $\frac{N-1}{R}+1$.

Comment: Inequality of Bombieri (11) from Montgomery's survey: is not it just a particular case of Schur test? I start suspecting that there is a lack of communication between number. theory and harm. analysis.